# Double Boot Windows 10 (two licenses, different SSDs) PC looses folder sharing configuration when booting with the other Windows install

Tags: windows-10, networking, multi-boot, network-shares, sharing

My PC with double boot Windows 10 (twice) has other HDs with folders I need to share on an (ethernet) network. Both installs can access network shared folders on other machines fine, however, the folders shared in this double boot machine loose configuration every time I alternate between OSs (folders can't be accessed by other machines). If I just reboot the same OS, it keeps the configuration fine and other machines can access files in it's internal drives.

For KVM (Barrier) to work on both Windows 10 installs (with another machine on the network), I named the computer the same on both installs, and it's working fine.

I made drive letters on both Windows installs the same (using Disk Management), and it doesn't help.

I've been re-configuring every shared folder every time I boot alternating the Windows installs.

Is it possible to share this double boot PC's folders on a network, alternating the OSs, while keeping the configuration?

The OSs are installed on different drives that I enable/disable as needed on BIOS at boot. It doesn't happen very often that I need to alternate, and that is a secondary problem right now (to be able to boot using a simpler F12 option list).

Thank you for any info that might get me moving!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to share this double boot PC's folders on a network,
> alternating the OSs, while keeping the configuration?
>
> The OSs are installed on different drives that I enable/disable as
> needed on BIOS at boot.

Network folder sharing is apparently being lost at some shutdowns (to reboot). This is not completely uncommon.

**Best solution (on a single machine) to share folders:**  Use virtual machines. That works and I use this method.

**Alternate method:** Have a second physical machine that is the server for the two dual boot installs.  This will work as well if properly configured in each machine.

You could also keep documents you need on a USB drive that will connect with either machine that is running. These external drives can be very large.

Comment: Hi John.

I don't think that what's happening is some sort of corruption of sharing configuration because if I don't alternate between OSs, it keeps the sharing information. 

I am starting to understand that when we share a folder, the folder ownership changes (the folder specs are interfered with, that is, it's not the OS alone that keeps the sharing configuration).

I would rather not use a VM because I run heavy applications. And would prefer not to have to invest on a whole new machine, but I would like to thank you for your time.

Comment: You could also use a USB drive (instead of a physical machine) to keep a copy of documents you need. I amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you John, and that would, indeed, work. I Forgot to mention that, a shared external drive doesn't lose sharing configuration, from neither OS. However, I'm working with very large files that need high speed and large capacity drives.

For that, I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to configure the sharing information that goes into the shared folder specs.

Comment: You can get 2 TB external SSD drives so that may be an option for you.